# Upgrade JSF 2.2 to 2.3

Tags: jsf-2.2

Is there any requirements to do upgrade from JSF 2.2 to 2.3, or should I only change version in pom.xml? I meet some issues with composite component in mojarra 2.2.13, this is why I'm wondering upgrading could be a solution

**UPDATE**

What I can guess from I read is that CDI is not mandatory using 2.3, is it true (I just want to be certain)? If it is, using last version of Mojarra (2.2.17), does it make sense to still use JSF 2.2 today?

Comment: I do not think JSF2.3 version is stable right now

Comment: Just three letters... T R Y. Run your app. If you encounter errors, don't use it or try to fix them. If you don't encounter errors, use it.

Comment: Latest 2.2 is fine. 2.3 does not require cdi but it is advised to not wait too long to switch (especially seeing what deltaspike can add for you)